# Getting the right path with laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to get the uploaded image to database to show it in my view , but the path is wrong and it didn't back with the image :

the getting path is like that :

> http://localhost/prestige/public/admin/[%22http:////localhost//prestige//public//uploads//services//icons//24//0.jpg%22]

and the image path at database is like that:

> ["http://localhost/prestige/public/uploads/services/24/0.jpg"]

And the view here it's:

```
 <img src="{{$service->services_image}}" alt="" height="200" width="200">
```

Can anyone help me with that ?

--- Update---
here it's the controller for upload the images :

```
if(!File::exists(('uploads/services/'.$services->id))) mkdir(('uploads/services/'.$services->id), 0777);


            if ($request->services_image){
            foreach($request->services_image as $key=>$pic){

                $url = [];
                $ext = $pic->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $pic->move(('uploads/services/'.$services->id .'/'), $key.'.'.$ext);


                if (! is_null(Service::find($services->id)->services_image)){
                    $url = Service::find($services->id)->services_image;
                } 

                $url[] = url('uploads/services/'.$services->id .'/'. $key.'.'.$ext);

                Service::find($services->id)->update(['services_image' => NULL]);

                Service::find($services->id)->update(['services_image' => json_encode($url)]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `src="{{asset($service->services_image)}}"`

Comment: It's back with wrong url too : 
http://localhost/prestige/public/admin/[%22http:////localhost//prestige//public//uploads//services//icons//24//0.jpg%22]

Comment: Can you post the code where you store the image path in your database?

Comment: Why are you assigning to an array exactly? And why are you storing as JSON? This part doesn't make any sense to me

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you ought to look at how you're storing the image path. If you're not expecting it to be in an array, you must be assigning it oddly. You can override the way assignment works with:

```
public function setServicesImageAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['services_image'] = $value;
}
```

You can modify the assignment in this way.

Similarly, you can modify retrieval using:

```
public function getServicesImageAttribute($value)
{
    return $value;
}
```

Just modify how you expect it to be retrieved here.

Since it's JSON data, you could configure it as JSON using `property $casts = ['services_image' => 'json'];`, this then handles JSON assignment and retrieval for you. (I can't remember off the top of my head if by default everything is always in a JSON object though, so do look up what you're doing for assignment as you clearly didn't expect that behaviour).

If for some reason you keep it in a JSON array, just modify the getter to `return json_decode($value)[0];` if you want to extract it from the JSON array.

It might be worth stripping the domain from assignment and using the `url()` helper to solve that problem for you. That decouples you from the domain you're working under if you reuse the database for some reason. It also means you don't have to strip the domain when you manipulate it with something like the `File` facade.

Answer (score 0):

The [`asset()` helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-asset) is typically used for this - it'll construct a URL with your app's `public` directory as the base.

Comment: I have tried that but not working too , it's back with this url 
http://localhost/prestige/public/admin/[%22http:////localhost//prestige//public//uploads//services//icons//24//0.jpg%22]

Comment: Then `$service->services_image` is not what you expect it to be. Dump it out with `dd()` and see what it contains.